# Joined values don't match?

Tags: sql, join, parquet, impala

My join is producing results that I don't understand.

If it's important or relevant, I'm using Parquet Tables in Impala.

What I'm doing is:

```
create table test1(foo string, bar int) stored as parquet;
create table test2(foo string, bar int) stored as parquet;
insert into test1 values ("something1",1);
insert into test2 values ("something2",2);
```

Checking to make sure that works:

```
 select * from test1;
```

Gives me the output:

```
+----------------------+
| foo      | bar |
+----------------------+
| something1 | 1     |
+----------------------+
1 rows
```

And

```
 select * from test2;
```

Gives me the output:

```
+----------------------+
| foo      | bar |
+----------------------+
| something2 | 2     |
+----------------------+
1 rows
```

Everything seems fine so far.  But now when I try to join these 2 tables with

```
 select * from test1 left outer join test2 using (foo);
```

I get:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| foo      | bar | foo      | bar |
+---------------------------------------------+
| something1 | 1     | something2 | 2     |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 rows
```

That's unexpected.  I expected the output to be something1, 1, null, null.  Shouldn't the join only happen when test1.foo = test2.foo?

I also tried doing this with syntax join on test1.foo = test2.foo as well as with an inner join and saw the same results.

Can someone please explain to me what's going on here?  I reread the documentation and I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: You are doing an left outer join, you want an inner join surely? You are also using a column that doesn't match... Hence the result set when using an outer join

Comment: I want to do a left outer join.  This is a boiled down version of something I'm observing in a much larger data set.  Trying to replicate the issue with simplest and smallest data set of 2 tables with 1 row each.

And as mentioned, if I use inner join, the output is the same

Comment: I think you have over-simplified the problem.  As stated, this is ludicrous behavior and would be indicative of a bug in the database.

Comment: This is literally the input and output.  Unless oversimplification could cause this ludicrous behavior, I was also thinking something is fundamentally wrong.  For what it's worth, in the larger data set, this mismatch of join only happens once every few million rows

Comment: `select * from test1 left outer join test2 using (foo)` should return columns `foo, bar, bar`; you should "expect" `(something1,1,null)`. Are you sure you are catching all warnings & errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: it appears to be an engineering bug.  Thanks for the help and feedback, all

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from test1 left outer join test2 on test1.foo=test2.foo
```

Comment: As mentioned in my second to last paragraph, I tried that with the same output.  I thought it could have overlooked a use case of using vs on.

Comment: that's strange , but try to upgrade the version of Impala or use a different version